# XPath returning empty array using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri, mechanize

I'm trying to parse a page using Nokogiri, Mechanize, and XPath, though, whatever I try, I receive an empty array.

[image: Page I'm trying to Parse.]

I inspected it in Chrome and got the XPath, then tried multiple ways to parse it but always received an empty array.

I tried:

```
puts page.search('/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]').inspect

puts  post_page.parser.xpath('/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]').inspect

puts  post_page.parser.at_xpath('/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]').inspect
```

All with and without a trailing "/text"

This is the source of the page I'm trying to scrape:

```
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
<!-- 
document.cookie = "IV_JCT=%2FMPIS; path=/";
//--> 
</SCRIPT>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>

  <head>
    <title>My Schedule</title>

    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1">    
    <meta http-equiv="keywords" content="keyword1,keyword2,keyword3">
    <meta http-equiv="description" content="This is my schedule">
    <!--
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    -->

  </head>

  <body>
  <div align="center"> 
    <strong>My Schedule</strong><br>as of Sun Feb 24 2013 06:43:09 PM CST<br><br>
    <div align="left"><pre><br>Employee Name: Johnson Appleseed    
Unit = 12345</pre>    
    <br> 
  </div>

    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
     <tr>
     <td colspan="8" align="center"><b><font size="+1">Schedules may be subject to change based on business needs or demand</font></b></td>
     </tr>   

      <tr><td>
      <table border="4" bordercolor="#2D73B9" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" width="100%">
      <tr bgcolor="#7C9BCF">
        <td width="12%" align="center"><b>Sunday</b></td>
        <td width="12%" align="center"><b>Monday</b></td>
        <td width="12%" align="center"><b>Tuesday</b></td>
        <td width="12%" align="center"><b>Wednesday</b></td>
        <td width="12%" align="center"><b>Thursday</b></td>
        <td width="12%" align="center"><b>Friday</b></td>
        <td width="12%" align="center"><b>Saturday</b></td>
        <td rowspan="2" width="12%" align="center"><b>Total weekly Hours</b></td>
      </tr>  

      <tr bgcolor="#7C9BCF">

        <td width="14%" align="center">2013-02-24</td>

        <td width="14%" align="center">2013-02-25</td>

        <td width="14%" align="center">2013-02-26</td>

        <td width="14%" align="center">2013-02-27</td>

        <td width="14%" align="center">2013-02-28</td>

        <td width="14%" align="center">2013-03-01</td>

        <td width="14%" align="center">2013-03-02</td>

      </tr>  

      <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

        <td width="14%" align="left"><pre>&nbsp;</pre></td>

        <td width="14%" align="left"><pre><b>Shift: </b>
5:30 PM - 9:00 PM
<b>Meal:</b>
 - </pre></td>


        <td width="14%" align="left"><pre>&nbsp;</pre></td>

        <td width="14%" align="left"><pre>&nbsp;</pre></td>

        <td width="14%" align="left"><pre>&nbsp;</pre></td>

        <td width="14%" align="left"><pre><b>Shift: </b>
2:00 PM - 9:15 PM
<b>Meal:</b>
5:45 PM - 6:30 PM</pre></td>

        <td width="14%" align="left"><pre><b>Shift: </b>
4:45 PM - 9:15 PM
<b>Meal:</b>
 - </pre></td>

        <td width="12%" align="center">14.5</td> 
      </tr>  

      <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

        <td width="14%" align="center">0.0</td>

        <td width="14%" align="center">3.5</td>

        <td width="14%" align="center">0.0</td>

        <td width="14%" align="center">0.0</td>

        <td width="14%" align="center">0.0</td>

        <td width="14%" align="center">6.5</td>

        <td width="14%" align="center">4.5</td>

        <td width="14%" align="center">Daily Hours</td>   
      </tr>  

     </table>
     </td></tr>

      <tr><td>
      <table border="4" bordercolor="#2D73B9" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" width="100%">
      <tr bgcolor="#7C9BCF">
        <td width="12%" align="center"><b>Sunday</b></td>
        <td width="12%" align="center"><b>Monday</b></td>
        <td width="12%" align="center"><b>Tuesday</b></td>
        <td width="12%" align="center"><b>Wednesday</b></td>
        <td width="12%" align="center"><b>Thursday</b></td>
        <td width="12%" align="center"><b>Friday</b></td>
        <td width="12%" align="center"><b>Saturday</b></td>
        <td rowspan="2" width="12%" align="center"><b>Total weekly Hours</b></td>
      </tr>  

      <tr bgcolor="#7C9BCF">

        <td width="14%" align="center">2013-03-03</td>

        <td width="14%" align="center">2013-03-04</td>

        <td width="14%" align="center">2013-03-05</td>

        <td width="14%" align="center">2013-03-06</td>

        <td width="14%" align="center">2013-03-07</td>

        <td width="14%" align="center">2013-03-08</td>

        <td width="14%" align="center">2013-03-09</td>

      </tr>  

      <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

        <td width="14%" align="left"><pre>Sched Not Posted</pre></td>

        <td width="14%" align="left"><pre>Sched Not Posted</pre></td>

        <td width="14%" align="left"><pre>Sched Not Posted</pre></td>

        <td width="14%" align="left"><pre>Sched Not Posted</pre></td>

        <td width="14%" align="left"><pre>Sched Not Posted</pre></td>

        <td width="14%" align="left"><pre>Sched Not Posted</pre></td>

        <td width="14%" align="left"><pre>Sched Not Posted</pre></td>

        <td width="12%" align="center">0.0</td> 
      </tr>  

      <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

        <td width="14%" align="center">0.0</td>

        <td width="14%" align="center">0.0</td>

        <td width="14%" align="center">0.0</td>

        <td width="14%" align="center">0.0</td>

        <td width="14%" align="center">0.0</td>

        <td width="14%" align="center">0.0</td>

        <td width="14%" align="center">0.0</td>

        <td width="14%" align="center">Daily Hours</td>   
      </tr>  

     </table>
     </td></tr>

      <tr><td>
      <table border="4" bordercolor="#2D73B9" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" width="100%">
      <tr bgcolor="#7C9BCF">
        <td width="12%" align="center"><b>Sunday</b></td>
        <td width="12%" align="center"><b>Monday</b></td>
        <td width="12%" align="center"><b>Tuesday</b></td>
        <td width="12%" align="center"><b>Wednesday</b></td>
        <td width="12%" align="center"><b>Thursday</b></td>
        <td width="12%" align="center"><b>Friday</b></td>
        <td width="12%" align="center"><b>Saturday</b></td>
        <td rowspan="2" width="12%" align="center"><b>Total weekly Hours</b></td>
      </tr>  

      <tr bgcolor="#7C9BCF">

        <td width="14%" align="center">2013-03-10</td>

        <td width="14%" align="center">2013-03-11</td>

        <td width="14%" align="center">2013-03-12</td>

        <td width="14%" align="center">2013-03-13</td>

        <td width="14%" align="center">2013-03-14</td>

        <td width="14%" align="center">2013-03-15</td>

        <td width="14%" align="center">2013-03-16</td>

      </tr>  

      <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

        <td width="14%" align="left"><pre>Sched Not Posted</pre></td>

        <td width="14%" align="left"><pre>Sched Not Posted</pre></td>

        <td width="14%" align="left"><pre>Sched Not Posted</pre></td>

        <td width="14%" align="left"><pre>Sched Not Posted</pre></td>

        <td width="14%" align="left"><pre>Sched Not Posted</pre></td>

        <td width="14%" align="left"><pre>Sched Not Posted</pre></td>

        <td width="14%" align="left"><pre>Sched Not Posted</pre></td>

        <td width="12%" align="center">0.0</td> 
      </tr>  

      <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

        <td width="14%" align="center">0.0</td>

        <td width="14%" align="center">0.0</td>

        <td width="14%" align="center">0.0</td>

        <td width="14%" align="center">0.0</td>

        <td width="14%" align="center">0.0</td>

        <td width="14%" align="center">0.0</td>

        <td width="14%" align="center">0.0</td>

        <td width="14%" align="center">Daily Hours</td>   
      </tr>  

     </table>
     </td></tr>

     <tr>
     <td colspan="8" align="center"><b><font size="+1">Schedules may be subject to change based on business needs or demand</font></b></td>
     </tr>
    </table >

        <p><br>
        </p>
        <p class="align_center" >      
            <input type=button value="Print this page" onClick="javascript:window.print();">     
            <input type=button value="Close This Window" onClick="javascript:window.close();">
        </p>

  </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: When providing code or data, such as the HTML, reduce it to the bare minimum necessary to demonstrate/reproduce the problem. Any more than that wastes our time and gets in the way of our being able to help you. Also, you don't say what it is you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 5):

Notice that in your XPath accessors you're requiring `tbody` be part of the path:

```
puts page.search('/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]').inspect
puts  post_page.parser.xpath('/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]').inspect
puts  post_page.parser.at_xpath('/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]').inspect
```

The HTML doesn't have a `tbody` tag, causing your lookup to fail.

Try simplifying your accessor. I usually start with CSS, which Nokogiri supports, then, if I can't get there I switch to XPath. Your mileage might vary for that.

For instance:

```
(rdb:1) puts doc.at('table table tr').to_html
```

Outputs:

```
<tr bgcolor="#7C9BCF">
<td width="12%" align="center"><b>Sunday</b></td>
        <td width="12%" align="center"><b>Monday</b></td>
        <td width="12%" align="center"><b>Tuesday</b></td>
        <td width="12%" align="center"><b>Wednesday</b></td>
        <td width="12%" align="center"><b>Thursday</b></td>
        <td width="12%" align="center"><b>Friday</b></td>
        <td width="12%" align="center"><b>Saturday</b></td>
        <td rowspan="2" width="12%" align="center"><b>Total weekly Hours</b></td>
        </tr>
```

That's a lot simpler way of getting at the column headers.

To get at the second row you can use:

```
(rdb:1) puts doc.at('table table tr[2]').to_html
```

Which gets you:

```
<tr bgcolor="#7C9BCF">
<td width="14%" align="center">2013-02-24</td>
        <td width="14%" align="center">2013-02-25</td>
        <td width="14%" align="center">2013-02-26</td>
        <td width="14%" align="center">2013-02-27</td>
        <td width="14%" align="center">2013-02-28</td>
        <td width="14%" align="center">2013-03-01</td>
        <td width="14%" align="center">2013-03-02</td>
        </tr>
```

To get at the cell contents you can use:

```
(rdb:1) puts doc.search('table table tr[2] td').map(&:text)
```

Which returns:

```
2013-02-24
2013-02-25
2013-02-26
2013-02-27
2013-02-28
2013-03-01
2013-03-02
2013-03-03
2013-03-04
2013-03-05
2013-03-06
2013-03-07
2013-03-08
2013-03-09
2013-03-10
2013-03-11
2013-03-12
2013-03-13
2013-03-14
2013-03-15
2013-03-16
```

Notice how that is returning the headings for two tables. To limit it to the first table we can use `at` instead of `search`. `at` returns the first matching node, where `search` returns a NodeSet, which is like an array. Also, `search` looks through the entire document finding all matches, unlike `at`'s behavior.

This code finds the first table's second row, then walks the embedded cells:

```
(rdb:1) puts doc.at('table table tr[2]').search('td').map(&:text)
2013-02-24
2013-02-25
2013-02-26
2013-02-27
2013-02-28
2013-03-01
2013-03-02
```

It's much simpler, easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: "Use the source, Luke!" Especially with something as badly abused as HTML.